# Why is the OBJECTID= 0 (zero)?

Tags: features, objectid

I consider myself fairly *new* to ArcGIS, in that I'm comfortable with all of the basic map-drawing functions. However, there are still things that confuse me.

I am working on a project where I must draw polygons to map landforms over an extensive area. Most features have an ObjectID number. However, there are some that simply have been assigned ObjectID= 0 (zero).

I do not see any immediate issues (ie features are still selectable, editable, etc).

Will there be problems that come up later if I don't address these odd ObjectID's? Why does ArcGIS assign an ObjectID of zero?

Comment: are you digitizing into a shapefile or a file geodatabase?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. AS a new user, please take the [Tour]. Zero is not a valid ObjectID value for file or enterprise geodatabase, but the ObjectID (aka registered rowid) column doesn't *have* to be `ObjectID` -- it could be `ObjectID_1`, and if it is, then if there was a NOT NULL ObjectID, it could be assigned zero as a "safe" value.  More details are necessary to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/fundamentals-of-objectid-fields.htm):

> The ObjectID field is maintained by ArcGIS and guarantees a unique ID
> for each row in a table.
>
> /snip...
>
> ObjectID fields are sequential and
> start with the number 1 for geodatabase data. **For shapefiles and
> dBASE tables, the OID or FID column begins at 0.**

Comment: I think DPSSpatial has a point, if the data was historically exported from a geodatabase  or has been joined or overlaid (union, intersect etc.) with a geodatabase table to a shapefile an OBJECTID field will exist but the rowid is FID, shapefiles don't support null so the OBJECTID will be 0 for new rows... cascademapper_30 my advice is to just ignore those fields until you've gained a little more experience with ArcGIS and there's something specific you want to do that requires a row's unique identifier.